# How to toggle the icon only if id matches?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, rest

After receiving data from the API then mapping it out - I tried toggling one icon, but it toggles all the icons that were mapped out. I am trying to click one of the icon and not all.

```
import { FaRegHeart, FaHeart } from "react-icons/fa";
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Replies = ({ comments, id }) => {
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);
    const [replies, setReplies] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
       const abortCont = new AbortController();
       fetch('http://192.168.1.98:5000/blogs/' + id, { signal: abortCont.signal })
       .then(res => {
          if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error('Could not get data from the database');
          }
          return res.json()
          })
       .then(data => setReplies(data))
       .catch(err => {
          if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
             // empty if statement
          }})

        return () => abortCont.abort()

    }, [liked])

    const likeComment = () => {liked ? setLiked(false) : setLiked(true)}

   return (
      <>
         {replies && <div className="commentSection">
            {
               replies.discussion.map((discussion) => (
                  <div key={discussion.id}>
                     <div className="commentEmoji">
                        {
                           liked ? <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: 'red', className: 'love-icon' }}>
                                      <FaHeart onClick={likeComment} />
                                   </IconContext.Provider>
                                  : <FaRegHeart onClick={likeComment} />}
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 ))}
             </div>
           }
      </>
   );
}

export default Replies;
```

This is what the API looks like:

```
"discussion": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "liked": false,
          "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg",
          "user": "Kayode",
          "comment": "They know electric vehicles are the future ",
          "replies": ""
        },
        {
          "user": "Farook",
          "liked": true,
          "id": 2,
          "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/74.jpg",
          "comment": "I hope they keep buying. TSLA to that freaking moon ",
          "replies": ""
        }
      ]
```

They have a `discussion.liked` property and I've been trying to access individual and not both.
If I use:

```
<FaRegHeart onClick={()=> likeComment(discussion.id)} />
```

Then

```
const likeComment = (id) => {
   console.log(id) //it logs the exact id of the icon i.e 2
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `discussion.liked` property?

Comment: Your context provider, should wrap both icons.

Comment: @AjithGopi yes i have a `discussion.liked` property

Comment: @Tobiasz if i wrapped one because i need to change the color if it has been liked

Comment: Try to split the component. Make a new component which is inside map loop.

Comment: @Shashank approach would be better!

Comment: Yes, because he is using one common state for all of the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import LikedComment from './LikedComment';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Replies = ({ comments, id }) => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [replies, setReplies] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortCont = new AbortController();

        fetch('http://192.168.1.98:5000/blogs/' + id, { signal: abortCont.signal })
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Could not get data from the database');
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setReplies(data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
                    // empty if statement
                } else {
                    setError(true);
                }
            });

        return () => abortCont.abort();
    }, [id]);

    const likeComment = (id) => {
        setReplies({
            ...replies,
            discussion: replies.discussion.map((reply) => {
                if (reply.id === id) {
                    return { ...reply, liked: !reply.liked };
                } else {
                    return reply;
                }
            }),
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            {error && <div className="commentError">Cannot retrieve comments </div>}
            {replies && (
                <div className="commentSection">
                    {replies.discussion.map((discussion, index) => (
                        <div key={discussion.id}>
                            <div className="comment">
                                <img className="commentImg" src={discussion.thumbnail} alt="" />
                                <div className="commentBody">
                                    <p>
                                        {' '}
                                        <span>{discussion.user}</span> {discussion.comment}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="commentEmoji">
                                    <LikedComment
                                        liked={discussion.liked}
                                        key={index}
                                        likeComment={() => likeComment(discussion.id)}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default Replies;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, and pass appropriate props in `LikedButton` component

```
import { FaRegHeart, FaHeart } from "react-icons/fa";
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const LikedButton = () => {
  const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);

  const likeComment = () => {liked ? setLiked(false) : setLiked(true)}

 return (
  <div >
  <div className="commentEmoji">
     {
        liked ? <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: 'red', className: 'love-icon' }}>
                   <FaHeart onClick={likeComment} />
                </IconContext.Provider>
               : <FaRegHeart onClick={likeComment} />}
    </div>
 </div>
 )
}

const Replies = ({ comments, id }) => {
    
    const [replies, setReplies] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
       const abortCont = new AbortController();
       fetch('http://192.168.1.98:5000/blogs/' + id, { signal: abortCont.signal })
       .then(res => {
          if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error('Could not get data from the database');
          }
          return res.json()
          })
       .then(data => setReplies(data))
       .catch(err => {
          if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
             // empty if statement
          }})

        return () => abortCont.abort()

    }, [])

    

   return (
      <>
         {replies && <div className="commentSection">
            {
               replies.discussion.map((discussion, index) => (
                  <LikedButton key={index} />
                 ))}
             </div>
           }
      </>
   );
}

export default Replies;
```

Comment: as long as the liked state is present, it will change the state of all the icons. thanks for helping tho